# Android NumberPicker widget looks different on emulator and graphical layout

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget, numberpicker, graphical-layout-editor

I am trying to put some number pickers into my application, yet their look is much different on the emulator and on the graphical layout. Here are screenshots:

This is how it looks like on emulator:
http://i40.tinypic.com/4sz9f4.png

And here is a screenshot from the Eclipse graphical layout:
http://i44.tinypic.com/2rzsw2a.png

I have read that you have to use either theme or theme.Holo but neither fix this. I would really like to know the way to fix it.

BTW. My emulator uses same API version as graphical layout.

Well I do not really need the look from the graphical layout, it would be enough if anyone could tell me how to change the color of the labels on the number picker, which appears in the emulator or a number picker which looks like the one from graphical layout.

Comment: what android version are you running the app?

Comment: Tried 4.1.2 and 4.2.2 same problem on both.

Comment: Actually I think it might have something to do with that the NumberPicker widget is internal, which means it is not in the public API.

Comment: BTW. I am using the build in graphical layout creator.

Comment: check the first 2 points in the doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html

Comment: As I have stated in the question I have already tried different themes, but none of them fix the problem.

Comment: the doc is right it will work if you do it right and it depends on the api version coz holo theme is available after api level 11 i guess

Comment: Well tried all of these things for api level 14, but well it was some time ago, I might give it a change when I'll have an opportunity to use Eclipse.

Comment: see the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993192/android-number-picker-default-design-changes-in-jelly-bean-and-ice-cream-sandwit/17993478#17993478

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have found this site, it contains instructions how to create a number picker which looks like the one I had in the graphical layout and wanted to have on my emulator.

Here is the link:

http://www.quietlycoding.com/?p=5

Cheers

But still I do not really know why the build-in number picker looks different on emulator and graphical layout.

You could also see this:
[http://stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993192/android-number-picker-default-design-changes-in-jelly-bean-and-ice-cream-sandwit/17993478#17993478)