# android number picker default design changes in jelly bean and ice-cream sandwitch

Tags: android, numberpicker

i've created an android application which displays a number picker, it all works fine...but the problem is with the design....when i run the application in gingerbread the number picker looks fine good....but when i run the same stuff in ice-cream sandwich and jelly bean the number picker design is been altered just like as shown below.

can anyone please tell me how to retain the default number-picker design that is in gingerbread in jelly bean

when runs in **ice-cream sandwich** and **jelly bean**

[image]

when runs in **ginger-bread**

[image]

i'm using a custom dialog box within which the number picker is placed, the code is as given below

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.app.Dialog; 
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.Window; 
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.NumberPicker; 

public class QuantityChangeDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener { 

public Activity c; 
public Dialog d; 
public Button save, cancel; 
NumberPicker np; 

public QuantityChangeDialog(Activity a) { 
super(a); 
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
this.c = a; 
} 


@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT)); 
setContentView(R.layout.selecteditem_dialog); 
save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save); 
cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel); 
save.setOnClickListener(this); 
cancel.setOnClickListener(this); 
np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.qntypicker); 
np.setMaxValue(120); 
np.setMinValue(1); 
np.setValue(3); 

} 

@Override 
public void onClick(View v) { 
switch (v.getId()) { 
case R.id.btn_save: 
c.finish(); 
break; 
case R.id.btn_cancel: 
dismiss(); 
break; 
default: 
break; 
} 
dismiss(); 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from docs

**If the current theme is derived from Theme the widget presents the current value as an editable input field with an increment button above and a decrement button below.** Long pressing the buttons allows for a quick change of the current value. Tapping on the input field allows to type in a desired value.

You need to set your theme that is derieved from `Theme` like fro example  `Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Open" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

dialog.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:theme = "@style/cust_dialog"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/numberPicker1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numberPicker1"
        android:text="Cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/numberPicker1"
        android:text="Set" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then to display custom dialog

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener
{
    private  TextView tv;
    static Dialog d ;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                       tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
                else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        // set to normal color
                     tv.setTextColor(0);  
                }

                return true;
            }


            });
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
         b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
         {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 show();
            }
            });
           }
     @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {

         Log.i("value is",""+newVal);

     }

    public void show()
    {


         final Dialog d=new Dialog(this,R.style.cust_dialog);
         d.setTitle("NumberPicker");
         d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
         Button b1 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button1);
         Button b2 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button2);
         final NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) d.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
         np.setMaxValue(100);
         np.setMinValue(0);
         np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
         np.setOnValueChangedListener(this);
         b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
         {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              tv.setText(String.valueOf(np.getValue()));
              d.dismiss();
           }    
          });
         b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
         {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              d.dismiss();
           }    
          });
       d.show();


    }
}
```

Styles.xml

```
</style>
  <style name="cust_dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"> 
</style>
```

Snap Shot

[image]

Comment: i've set the theme to Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen but still i could'nt find any design change in number picker........it still displaying as shown in the first above pic......

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752619/about-the-full-screen-and-no-titlebar-from-manifest

Comment: Yes sir it works but now the problem is that my whole application design has been changes

Comment: can we give theme only for number picker

Comment: @Denny use it for only the activity that has the numberpicker. set the theme for the activity in manifest that has number picker.

Comment: sir actually my number picker is within a dialogue box

Comment: @Denny you can set themes only for the dialog

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34625/discussion-between-denny-and-raghunandan)

Answer (score 2):

You can just add this attribute into your NumberPicker

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

E.g.

```
<NumberPicker   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This will limit the impact to just the number picker widget, not the entire activity page.

Comment: yes but how to set election divider and text colors in the theme?

Comment: I mean "selection divider"